# Force visual studio 2012 compiler to use C++ TR1 (2007 standard)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to force the **visual studio compiler** to compile according to the **2007 C++ standard** (ISO/IEC TR 19768:2007, C++TR1)?

I have to avoid using any C++11 features in my current project, even though we already use the 2012 studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a parallel installation of e.g. VisualStudio 2008, you can use its compiler out of VS2012 for your C++ projects. This is done in the project's settings, via "Platform toolset".

Comment: Ok, so do I have to use only the 2008 compiler or the whole 2008 toolchain (linker, compiler,...)?

Comment: The whole toolchain I think.

Comment: This could be very complicated I think: all the compiler/linker parameters have to be translated and used from 2012 to 2008... But it could be a solution anyway.

Comment: You don't even want to bother with linking, or even code generation. You just want `/Zs` basically - check if it compiles as C++03+TR1. For the actual compilation, you'd use the VS2012 toolset.

Answer (score 0):

> to compile according to the 2007 C++ standard

No. Because VS2012 (or 2013) does not completely implement C++07 (despite including parts of the next – "C++14" – standard).

You'll need to specify which specific language or library features you are concerned about (and why would be helpful) for a more specific answer.

Comment: Background: there are several companies working on that project. Some of them already switched to 2012, others are still using 2008. So any Cx11 feature used in the code, will break their build.

Comment: I thought any compiler implementing C++11 is able to compile _any_ source code that was compilable with a C++07 compiler. So to speak C++07 contains a subset of C++11. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nabulke: No, but no version of Visual Studio has ever implemented any version of the C++ standard. There have always been major omissions.